# Edit curves lines and axes parameter option in Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When I run the following code on terminal:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 5, 1)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I get the following window:

[image]

But when I run the SAME code on Spyder, I get:

[image]

Why? And how I make the terminal generate the same interactive window?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609219/edit-curves-lines-and-axes-parameter-option-not-showing-in-matplotlib) they say it's because my `matplotlib` version is too old, but I already checked and it's the same (`1.5.1`) in both, Spyder and Terminal. Moreover, `Qt` and `PyQt` versions, `4.8.7` and `4.11.4` respectively, are the same in both, with both Spyder and terminal running `Python 2.7.12`.

I don't get why it is different. I wanna manipulate my graphs in a script, after generating them.

**The matplotlib version is updated to 2.0.2**

Thanks!

Comment: The latest version of matplotlib is 2.0.2

Comment: Have you tried updating your version of matplotlib?

Comment: I know, but I guess the difference is not int the `matplotlib` version, because get different results with the same version

Comment: I just ran it on spyder 3.1.4, python 2.7.13 and matplotlib 2.0.2 and I have no problems

Comment: I just upgraded it to 2.0.2 and I still have the same problem. The layout of the buttons in the window even changed, but by running it on terminal I still get the adjust options in the left bottom corner, without the option to adjust the lines, curves, etc and by running it in Spyder I get them on the right top corner, with this option.

Comment: Have you tried running it without spyder?

Comment: As I sad, if I run one script by opening it on spyder and run it there, I get the expected. 
If generate a plot in the console in spyder, I get it 

If I just run the same script by ./scripty.py in the terminal, I don't get it
If I open python on terminal and generate a plot there, I also don't get it

Comment: I found what I want. Spyder plots interactive plots while running it on terminal you get normal plot. You have to specify `matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')` just after calling matplotlib and before calling matplotlib.pyplot